# how can i get the parent of user control wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a problem i make a window application and using some Some Wpf user control on my Window Form i want to close my form When I close the user Control,Cancel button how can i achive it.....means i want to get the parent of usercontrol

Answer (score 8):

The parent of the `UserControl` you get with the [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent.aspx)-property. The window you can get directly with the [`Window.GetWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow.aspx)-method.

```
Window w=Window.GetWindow(this);
if(null != w){
    w.Close();
}
```